# Configuring Appenders

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I have the following situation.
There are 2 classes: ClassA, ClassB. I want them to log in different files ClassA.log, ClassB.log. For this purpose I am using the RollingFileAppender. How can I write this in a shorter way than the following:

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppenderA" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="ClassA.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFileAppenderB" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="ClassB.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

As you can see, the only thing the appenders differ is the filename where they are writing logs. So, is there a way to define a single RollingFileAppender for the given problem?

Comment: I believe the answer is no, there isn't a shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on several projects with multiple file appenders configured just like yours. To my knowledge **there is no way to define a common appender configuration** and then share that among multiple appenders. It probably has something to do with how log4net interprets the XML tags into Properties on the appenders. (And I have looked closely at the [`ForwardingAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#ForwardingAppender), but it's not built for that).

---

Is there any reason other than "don't repeat yourself" ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) that you want to clean up the configuration? If your app.config (or web.config) is getting out of hand, you can use a [separate](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#reading) configuration file.